# Paypal checkout usng credit card

Tags: checkout, paypal, credit-card

While checkout using paypal express checkout ,credit card payment without creating a paypal account is not showing for Switzerland. Is there any configurations to enable checkout using credit card ?

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that certain customers are not offered it based on cookies or similar. PayPal think they have an account. I would advise you to try another browser / incognito / private mode. First.

Second. There is also an option at PayPal according to their information.

https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/account-optional :
To turn the feature off, simply go to the Profile subtab, click on Website Payment Preferences under the Selling Preferences column, and check the yes/no box under PayPal Account Optional

Comment: the mentioned option is available for the same user for different country.So want to know is there any configurations for country specific?

Comment: What do you mean with same user? I'm not aware of any specific country constraints. There are cookies used for PayPal and PayPal will not likely allow one email to do unlimited amount of purchases without an account. Furthermore, are you sure there is not a pay with credit card option? The options sometimes becomes very small, could you share a print screen?